# Mongo warning: log line attempted (48kB) over max size (10kB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have my mongodb running on aws and when I checked the log, I discovered this warning:

```
warning: log line attempted (48kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... command feedposts command: find { find: "feedposts", filter: { hideUsers: { $nin: [ ObjectId('5d95f01a0fb23d3dc050e355') ] }, $or:[ { userId: { $in: [ ObjectId('5d9550aa6828c11af2435897'), ObjectId('5d95f01a0fb23d3dc050e355') etc
```

My concerns are:

1.Does this warning effect the performance of application?

2.Does this warning get saved in the log file?

3.How do I get rid of this warning?

4.My mongodb.log file size is getting bigger every second. Is this because of the warnings I am getting?

I wish for anyone's help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Excessive logging can have a impact on your app performance.
2. Depends on the log level you have set. A log level of "warn" and above will write those messages into the log file.
3. Set your log level to "error"
4. No idea. Look into your logfile and check what type of messages (error, warning, info, ...) are beeing logged.